# Database for Facility related items

Tags: database-design

I am trying to wrap my brain around creating database for keeping track of facility related items:
For example:

1. Electrical devices: panels, security readers, smoke detectors,
   speaker/gongs etc.
2. Plumbing devices: sprinkler heads, shut offs, fire hydrants etc.
3. Flooring records
4. Painting records
5. Hazmat testing/materials

….. and other too many to list here

The one common thread between them is their location. Any/each of them could be located at:

- Site (not attached to building)
- Attached to building (exterior):
  possible (but not guaranteed to know the floor/level and or room).
- Inside building (interior): the exact room will be known

With my limited experience designing database tables I think there are two possible scenarios:

- Single table with (columns for): site, building, level, room. Any unknown or non-applicable field will be Null. It will be single table but lots of Nulls.
- 3x Separate tables: Site only, exterior building, Interior. And keep record of only relevant data. For site table record the Site ID only. For interior keep record of Room ID only. For building exterior I would record the Building ID (and level or room IF available).

Long story short, my questions boil down to 2 main issues:

- Do I deal with each subject/group locations separately or try to group them?
- Do I create a single table with lots of Nulls or 3X three separate tables?

Here are the possible combos for 5 subjects:

- Single table for all subjects and all locations grouped: Table Count = 1
- Single table for each subject and all locations grouped: Table Count = 5
- Single table per subject and each location: Table Count = 15.

I hope this makes any sense? I would appreciate any comment?
Thank you

Comment: You haven't given us enough information about your “items” and your “locations” for us to provide advice. What you are trying to do is called [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and is a difficult process. Read the article. Apply the Normal Forms in sequence. If you get into trouble, edit your post to show what you have.

Comment: This has nothing to do with "Normalization". The location possibilities are clearly shown: 1. Site only (not attached to building( for example: near the main site gate). 2. Externally attached to a building (optionally possible to specify level/floor and room (for example: outside/second floor/classroom 122). 3. Internally located (for example: Classroom 121). PS. Knowing the room of course you know the realated floor/building/site

Comment: Also the following imaginary tables are related: sites/buildings/floors/rooms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically the answer to how to design a database depends on the questions asked of the data.  Do you want to know all Hazmat materials at a particular site?  Then, as suggested in the comments, you'll need a normalized database.

A workaround would be to create a Locations table with a description, location type (site/building/floor/etc.) and locationID.  Then you could add a ParentLocation field to link the room to the floor, the floor to the building, etc.  The benefit is you could add/take away levels without changing any tables. You could store the various ID's in the item record and the parent information would be automatically available.

If there are any fields specific to each location type though you'd still want to have separate tables.

Comment: JJ32.Typically the answer to how to design a database depends on the questions asked of the data. This first sentence gets you my vote. The location part also makes somewhat sense but i don't think it applies to my situation. Thanks